# Constructor in parent class cannot be applied

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a program that takes different shapes of carpets and creates a carpet object with certain variables defined in the subclasses.  My code is

```
public abstract class Carpet{

protected int area = 0;
protected double unitPrice = 0;
protected double totalPrice = 0.0;
protected String carpetID;

public Carpet(String id, double thisPrice){
    carpetID = id;
    unitPrice = thisPrice;
}

public String getCarpetId(){
    return carpetID;
}

public String toString(){
    String carpet = new String("\n" + "The CarpetId:\t\t" + getCarpetId() + "\nThe Area:\t\t" + area + "\nThe Unit Price\t\t" + unitPrice + "\nThe Total Price\t" + totalPrice + "\n\n");
    return carpet;
}

public abstract void computeTotalPrice();

}
```

and the subclass is

```
public class CircleCarpet extends Carpet{

private int radius;

public CircleCarpet(String id, double priceOf, int rad){
    radius = rad;
    super.unitPrice = priceOf;
    computeTotalPrice();

}

public void computeTotalPrice(){
    super.area = radius * radius * 3;
    super.totalPrice = area * unitPrice;
}


public String toString(){
    String forThis = new String("\nThe Carpet Shape:\tCircle\nThe radius:\t\t" + radius + "\n");
    return forThis + super.toString();
}

}
```

But whenever I try to compile the subclass I get the error

```
11: error: constructor Carpet in class Carpet cannot be applied to given types;
public CircleCarpet(String ID, double priceOf, int rad){
                                                       ^


 required: String,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your super class doesn't have a `no-args default constructor,` you need to explicitly call your super class constructor from your sub-class constructor using [**super()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).Not that this has to be the first line in your sub-class constructor.

```
 public CircleCarpet(String ID, double priceOf, int rad){
    super(ID, priceOf)
    radius = rad;
    super.unitPrice = priceOf;
    computeTotalPrice();

}
```

**An Advice:**

Follow Java naming conventions, variable names should be camelCase. i., in this case `id` is more appropriate than `ID`.

Comment: That worked, thank you.  Now to figure out why the parseStringToCarpet class won't work..

Comment: @user2032938 you are welcome, i dont see `parseStringToCarpet ` in your code

Comment: You should probably remove the `super.unitPrice = priceOf` line, since it's redundant.

Comment: The parseStringToCarpet is a different class, I needed to find out what was wrong with the CircleCarpet before I could try to fix it.

Comment: I will, I just have to wait 3 more minutes before it will let me.